# Issue with absolutely positioned div nested within another absolutely positioned div

Tags: css, css-position

I'm no CSS expert, especially when it comes positioning, and I'm hopeful that this one will be easy to solve.

Here is my simplified HTML:

```
<body>
    <div style="height:100%;width:100%;">
        <div id="map" style="bottom:250px;height:100%;overflow:hidden;position:absolute;width:100%;">
            <!-- The controls div does not render correctly. -->
            <div id="controls" style="left:10px;position:absolute;top:10px;">
            </div>
            <!-- The legend and logos divs do render correctly. -->
            <div id="legend" style="bottom:45px;left:10px;position:absolute;">
            </div>
            <div id="logos" style="bottom:5px;left:10px;position:absolute;">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="search" style="bottom:0;height:250px;position:absolute;width:100%;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The "controls" div is not rendering correctly. In fact, it doesn't display at all. If I take out the "top:10px;" style, and replace it with "bottom:400px;", it does render correctly. This is not what I want, though, as the "map" div's height gets adjusted if the user resizes the browser window. I also do not want to use JavaScript to position the div.

The "legend" and "logos" divs are both rendering correctly.

I'm doing my testing in Firefox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I ended up with. Thanks, Sarfraz and sholsinger, for leading me in the right direction:

```
<body>
    <div style="height:100%;width:100%;">
        <div style="bottom:250px;position:absolute;top:0;width:100%">            
            <div id="map" style="height:100%;overflow:hidden;position:relative;width:100%;">
                <div id="controls" style="left:10px;position:absolute;top:10px;">
                </div>
                <div id="legend" style="bottom:45px;left:10px;position:absolute;">
                </div>
                <div id="logos" style="bottom:5px;left:10px;position:absolute;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="search" style="bottom:0;height:250px;position:absolute;width:100%;">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

So I basically just nested the "map" div in an absolutely positioned div and set it to "position;relative;".

There were two problems in the example I first posted:

1. As pointed out by sholsinger, the height of my "map" div was set to 100%, and this was sizing the div to 100% of the browser window. The "bottom:250px;" was simply pushing that div up and off the page. This was causing the controls to render off screen. I could have simply setup a new style on "controls" ("margin-top:260px;") to get the display working correctly, but this would not have solved the underlying problem correctly.
2. As pointed out by Sarfraz, the "map" div needed to have "position:relative;" defined on it so the absolutely positioned controls would display correctly.

The fixes above solve both of these problems.

Answer (score 7):

You should simply give the **parent** div a position set to `relative` and **children** `absolute`. This CSS trick is explained here:

- [Absolute Positioning Inside Relative Positioning](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

Comment: Right, but if I set "map" to "position:relative;" it does not render correctly.

Comment: Agreed. The `#controls` div is probably being rendered, but you have `overflow:hidden` on the parent so it is being drawn outside of the parent and therefore not being shown. Also, if the parent div `#map` is extending `250px` beyond the top of the page (which it should be if your CSS is being rendered right) then the controls would be off-screen anyway.

Comment: @Nate: if you remove the `bottom:250px` and then change `position:relative` on `div#map` then the inner div should be where you want it.

Comment: @sholsinger: I tried the change (setting "position:relative;" on div#map and removing "bottom:250px;"), but this causes the map to fill the entire window. The "height:100%" means it is getting the full height of its parent, which is the full height of the browser window. That said, the controls are now rendering where I want them to.

Comment: @sholsinger: What you said makes perfect sense, though; I do think that the controls are rendering correctly. They are just displaying 250px over the browser viewport.